# Compact embedding from Lipschitz set of functions into continuous set

Tags: banach-spaces, compactness, compact-operators

We note $E=\Biggl\{f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R},~\sup\limits_{x\neq x'}\frac{\vert f(x)-f(x')\vert}{\vert x-x'\vert^\frac{1}{2}}<\infty\Biggr\}$

I have showed that $(E,\Vert\cdot\Vert_E)$ is a Banach space with 
$$
\Vert f\Vert_E = \vert f(0)\vert+\sup\limits_{x\neq x'}\frac{\displaystyle\vert f(x)-f(x')\vert}{\displaystyle\vert x-x'\vert^\frac{1}{2}}
$$

Now, I have to show that 
$$
id\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
\displaystyle E&\to& \mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})\\
\displaystyle f&\mapsto& f
\end{array}
\right.
$$
is compact, where $\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

My try: 
Considering a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that is uniformly $\Vert\cdot\Vert_E$-bounded, I can show that it implies that it is uniformly bounded for $\Vert f\Vert_{\mathcal{C([0,1],\mathbb{R})}}=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\vert f(x)\vert$ as $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\mathcal{C([0,1],\mathbb{R})}}\leqslant\Vert\cdot\Vert_E$, but I do not know how to proceed next.

If you could indicate the steps to follow, that would be great, thanks !

Comment: You want to show that $E$ is compact ? Thats the question ?

Comment: I want to show that the operator $id$ is compact, that is if we get a $\Vert\cdot\Vert_E$-bounded subset $A\subset E$, then $\overline{id(A)}$ is compact with respect to the $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})}$-norm.

Comment: The operator is continous isn't it ?

Comment: Yes it is, as stated in my post. But that is not enough to show that it is compact, isn't it ?

Comment: Have you tried Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem?

Comment: @user90189
I forgot I could use that, thanks a lot!